# pip install inside the conda environment

Tags: pip, conda

I have  the following setup inside the condarc file:

```
ssl_verify: true
use_pip: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
proxy_servers:
  http: proxyserver
  https: proxyserver
```

I am using Anaconda behind the company proxy that those details about the proxy servers are mentioned under the http: and https: fields.

Once I activate the environment and issue the following command :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 
0x000002A615C950D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/jinja2/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an SSL error to me. I fixed it by bypassing as shown below:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt —trusted-host pypi.org —trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

If you are in a corporate network it may occur due to firewall blockage. Try the above solution.